# Access properties of an array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is the array:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Meowsy",
    "species" : "cat",
    "foods": {
      "likes": ["tuna", "catnip"],
      "dislikes": ["ham", "zucchini"]
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Barky",
    "species" : "dog",
    "foods": {
      "likes": ["bones", "carrots"],
      "dislikes": ["tuna"]
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Purrpaws",
    "species" : "cat",
    "foods": {
      "likes": ["mice"],
      "dislikes": ["cookies"]
    }
  }
]
```

This is my JS code:

```
(function($){
    $('button').on( 'click', function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/LearnWebCode/json-example/master/animals-1.json',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data){
        $('p').html(data[0].name)
      }
    })
  })
})(jQuery)
```

With that I can show `Meowsy` but what I want is the dog name (Barky) and dislikes (tuna), how can I do that?

https://jsfiddle.net/g1rjwL7y/

Comment: `$('p').html(data[1].name + ' dislikes ' + data[1].dislikes.join(' '))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

barky = `data[1].name`

tuna = `data[1].foods.dislikes[0]`

Answer (score 0):

your data is like

```js
let data=
      [ { "name"    : "Meowsy"
        , "species" : "cat"
        , "foods"   : { "likes"    : ["tuna", "catnip"]
                      , "dislikes" : ["ham", "zucchini"]
                      }
        }
      , { "name"    : "Barky"
        , "species" : "dog"
        , "foods"   : { "likes"    : ["bones", "carrots"]
                      , "dislikes" : ["tuna"]
                      }
        }
      , { "name"    : "Purrpaws"
        , "species" : "cat"
        , "foods"   : { "likes"    : ["mice"]
                      , "dislikes" : ["cookies"]
                      }
        } 
      ]


BarkySearh = data.find(e=>e.name==='Barky')  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

console.log ( BarkySearh.foods.dislikes[0]) // -> tuna
```